# Transfer Learning on Resnets/VGGs -- Validation accuracy can never be over 75%

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, transfer-learning, inceptionresnetv2

I am trying to classify skin cancer images into two categories -- malignant and benign. Literatures suggest that using pre-trained resnet/vgg network achieves more than 90% accuracy. However, with my dataset, whatever I try, the validation accuracy can never be greater than 75%.

I am using a well-balanced dataset where there are 500 malignant and 500 benign images in the training dataset. The number of images is on a smaller end; however, the fact that I am using transfer learning and other literatures showing that with only ~1000 images they could achieve more than 90% accuracy, I believe there's something wrong with the transfer learning logic than the data itself.

I additionally have tried the followings:

- Used different number of batches (8/16/32/64/128) and different learning rates (from 1e-7 to 0.1)
- "unfreezed (change require_grad=False to True)" the pretrained resnet/vgg after the validation error platues and updated the weights for smaller epochs (a.k.a. fine tuning the pretrained network after setting require_grad=True after validation accuracy platues)
- Decayed the learning rate using scheduler
- used other nets: inception v3, GoogleNet
- rather than having one fully connected layer, used dropout-FC-relu-FC

This is the core logic:

```
model_ft = models.resnet18(pretrained=True) # some other place in my code, I set all of resnet18 param to require_grad=False
num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)

model_ft = model_ft.to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer_ft = optim.SGD(model_ft.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

and this is how I normalize my data (I have tried cropping, rotating, and horizontal-flipping; none of these boosted the performance. For now, in order to preserve some relevant clinical features, I decided not to touch the data):

```
data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
}
```

Can someone please let me know what I could do to improve the model performance? Without too much of a data pre-processing, we think the model should achieve well-above 85% accuracy in the validation set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a Contest in Kaggle - [SIIM-ISIC Melanoma Classification](https://www.kaggle.com/c/siim-isic-melanoma-classification/overview).
  In this contest also tasks for participants to classify two class: **malignant & benign**.

But in the dataset, there were the same images in both the class. And this produces the **Dataleakage**.

**Dataleakage**,  also can produce in the same class images both in the training and in the validation set.

And to solve this problem Chris Deotte(Kaggle Grandmaster), Applied **RAPIDS cuML kNN using CNN embeddings for finding the similar images** and then remove those image.
[Here are link of the Chris Deotte Kaggle Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/cdeotte/rapids-cuml-knn-find-duplicates?scriptVersionId=38904596).

This is the one solution to detect similar images for classes if the model does not work well. There are obviously other factors to improving model accuracy. Best of luck.